# scss intellisense: how to exclude all folders except one for sees the variables for autosuggestions?

Tags: variables, sass, intellisense, vscode-extensions, autosuggest

Here is the problem: I use scss intellisense to had access to my variables (variables of colors, fonts etc), but this extension sees unnecessary variables in all folders on my VSCode workspace. But I need to scan only in my ./src/scss/ folder for autosuggestions. Scss intellisense have **"scss.scannerExclude"** property to deny some folders, but I need to deny all folders except one, and I don't understand how to write a rule for it. Can somebody help me?)

Here is a template of my project folder:

- Folder to exclude
- Folder to exclude
- Folder to exclude (There may be more than 3 of them).
- src

  - img
  - scss - need to scan only this folder to get variables
  - js
- index.html

P.S. - sorry for my English. (●'◡'●)

I tried to write some rules in **"scss.scannerExclude"** like: **"**/**(!src)"**, but it doesn't work.

I'm expecting scss intellisense to sees the variables **only in my ./src/ or /src/scss folders**.